# postgres superuser issues during pg_upgrade

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, pg-upgrade

I'm using homebrew on Mac OSX to manage a postgres database.  I'm trying to upgrade my postgres install from 11.9 to 13.0 using pg_upgrade.  When I run pg_upgrade I get the following error about not being a superuser.  If I try running as the "postgres" user, I get an error that the "postgres" user is not the install user.

```
pg_upgrade --old-datadir /usr/local/var/postgresql@11 --new-datadir /usr/local/var/postgres --old-bindir /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.9/bin --new-bindir /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.0/bin -c -U Brian
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok

connection to database failed: FATAL:  must be superuser to connect in binary upgrade mode

could not connect to source postmaster started with the command:
"/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.9/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/usr/local/var/postgresql@11" -o "-p 50432 -b  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700 -c unix_socket_directories='/usr/local/Cellar'" start
Failure, exiting
```

Try as the "postgres" user

```
pg_upgrade --old-datadir /usr/local/var/postgresql@11 --new-datadir /usr/local/var/postgres --old-bindir /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.9/bin --new-bindir /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.0/bin -c -U postgres
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is the install user
database user "postgres" is not the install user
```

My system username is "Brian" and the original 11.9 database was installed as that user, but somehow it does not have superuser rights.  I'm not sure how that happened but never quite realized it until now.  My 13.0 database seems to be correctly set up with "Brian" as a superuser.

```
template1=# \du+
                                 List of roles
   Role name   |             Attributes              | Member of  | Description
---------------+-------------------------------------+------------+-------------
 Brian         | Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}         |
```

When I login with `psql -d template1 -U postgres` and try to alter the role I get the following error.

```
template1=# alter role Brian with superuser;
ERROR:  role "brian" does not exist
Time: 0.415 ms
```

If I log in as `sudo -u postgres -i` and try to alter or create a user, I also get the following errors:

```
psql -c "alter role Brian with superuser;"
ERROR:  role "brian" does not exist

createuser -s Brian
createuser: error: creation of new role failed: ERROR:  role "Brian" already exists
```

Does anyone know why postgres is confused over "Brian" and "brian" and how I can give superuser rights the role "Brian" so I can properly perform a pg_upgrade?  When I tried `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` it initially gave me the same superuser error and now, upon rerun, it says that everything is already upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case of SQL identifiers from within SQL is ignored except when in double quotes:

```
alter role "Brian" with superuser;
```

But when specified on the command line (with -U, for example) case is not ignored.

Comment: Ha.  Well how about that.  I've been using postgres for years and never knew that little fact.  All this time... Thanks.  That did the trick!